# I want to write a django-python method that will send remainder email to a user, on specified date

Tags: python, django

this is my model.py, with send_email method to send email on time that i have been specified 
on geting_date().

```py
# Function to set a deadline
def geting_date():
    initial_date = datetime.date(2019,12,1) # initial date
    deadline = initial_date + datetime.timedelta(days=23,hours=14, minutes=44)# deadline date 

    return deadline

# model contains reports
class ReportType(models.Model):

    ICYUMWERU = 1
    IGIHEMBWE = 2
    UMWAKA = 3
    TIME_CHOICES = (
        (ICYUMWERU, 'Icyumweru'),
        (IGIHEMBWE, 'Igihembwe'),
        (UMWAKA, 'Umwaka'),
    )

    r_type = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    igihe_itangirwa = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=TIME_CHOICES, default=1)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, models.CASCADE)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, models.CASCADE)
    deadline = models.DateField(default=geting_date)





     # send email on specified date from geting_date() above
    def send_email(self):

            report_remainder = self.deadline
            if report_remainder:
                subject = "Welcome "
                message = 'We are in Reporting period you need to submitt your report on time !!!'
                rec = self.owner.email
                recepient = rec
                send_mail(subject, message, EMAIL_HOST_USER, [recepient], fail_silently = False)
```

But is not working anyone could help me

Comment: You need to call that method to send the email. But nothing calls send_email method right now.

Comment: Btw, your whole approach is wrong. You are not supposed to send mails from a model's method. Can you read and try this https://medium.com/@EmadMokhtar/send-emails-asynchronously-from-django-3c1e41b526c3 . Then ask again if you have problems at any point.